# On click check all the rows values of a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table where I have multiple rows and for each row I have check button. On click of the button on each row i have to check that row customerno is already present in any of the rows and highlight all the rows whose girno is less than the selected row for the same customerno. I am not able to compare that one row value to other all rows.

On click I am able to get the current row customerno and girno but i am stuck to continue to compare it on others row for same selected customerno.

```
 <table class="pr_indextable">
 <tr class=".prRow">
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox("jobcardproduct1", array('class'=>'selectcheck'));?></td>
  <td class="customerno">22</td>
  <td class="girno">GIR1</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class=".prRow">
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox("jobcardproduct2", array('class'=>'selectcheck'));?></td>
  <td class="customerno">223</td>
  <td class="girno">GIR2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class=".prRow">
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox("jobcardproduct3", array('class'=>'selectcheck'));?></td>
  <td class="customerno">22</td>
  <td class="girno">GIR3</td>
 </tr>

   <tr class=".prRow">
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox("jobcardproduct3", array('class'=>'selectcheck'));?></td>
  <td class="customerno">22</td>
  <td class="girno">GIR4</td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).find(".prRow").each(function(){
        var inqrow=this;
        $(inqrow).find(".selectcheck").click(function(){
            var ischecked= $(this).is(':checked');
            if(ischecked){
                 var girno=$(inqrow).find(".girno").val();
                 var customerno=$(inqrow).find(".customerno").val();  
                $(inqrow).css('background-color','#3c8dbc');
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

expected: on click of select button highlight the rows whose girno is less than other rows of same customerno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> highlight the rows whose girno is less than other rows of same customerno.

in your example code `girno` is not a `number` so you can't compare them,
in my code i assumed that `girno` is `number`.
*here is the working solution*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.selectcheck').change(function () {
                var rows = $('.pr_indextable tr'); //rows in table
                if ($(this).is(`:checked`)) {

                    let customerNumber = $(this).parent().next().text(); 
                    //selected customer number
                    let girNumber = $(this).parent().next().next().text(); //selected girNumber
                    
                    // iterate over all rows and check 

                    $.each(rows, function (i, item) {

                        // if current row's cutomer number is same as selected row's customer number

                        if ($(this).find('.customerno').text() == customerNumber) {

                            //compare the girnumber of current row and selected row
                            if ($(this).find('.girno').text() < girNumber) {
                                
                                //hight the row
                                $(this).css('background-color', '#3c8dbc');
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            //remove highligh, if have any
                            $(this).css('background-color', 'initial');
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    //if unchecked than remove highlight
                    $.each(rows, function (params) {
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'initial');
                    })
                }
            })
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="pr_indextable">
        <tr class=".prRow">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectcheck" /></td>
            <td class="customerno">22</td>
            <td class="girno">1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class=".prRow">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectcheck" /></td>
            <td class="customerno">223</td>
            <td class="girno">2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class=".prRow">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectcheck" /></td>
            <td class="customerno">22</td>
            <td class="girno">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class=".prRow">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectcheck" /></td>
            <td class="customerno">22</td>
            <td class="girno">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```